# HashMap get(Key) function not working in Android AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, hashmap

I am trying to get a value from a `HashMap` that is passed in as a parameter to an `AsyncTask`.  The `get(Key)` method doesn't resolve; my IDE states

> "Cannot resolve method 'get(java.lang.String)'".

Here is the code in question:

```
public class AmayalockAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, String>, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(HashMap... params) {

        String ACTION = params.get("action");

        return " ";
     }
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what I am missing.  It is acting like "params" is a String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you first need to retrieve the HashMap object from the array params as so:

```
protected String doInBackground(HashMap... params) {
    HashMap mapYouNeed = params[0];
    String ACTION = mapYouNeed.get("action");
    return ACTION;
}
```

The reason for retrieving the map first is because the input to an AsyncTask is an array. If you passed in just one HashMap, then you need to retrieve the element at index 0. The HashMap... paramas indicates that params is an array of HashMap elements.

Comment: Thanks @Sunil, I think that worked.  The only extra thing I needed to do was to type-cast the `map.get("action")` or else it keeps saying "Incompatible Types: Required java.lang.String, found java.lang.object".

Comment: Hmm.. I think that might have been because you created an HashMap without using generics possibly (?)

Comment: Hmm, not sure.  I tried `doInBackground(HashMap<String, String>... params)` but `map.get("action")` still requires it to be type cast to String.

Comment: When you create the Asynctask and pass in an HashMap, what are the generic parameters you pass there. For example, when you do new AmayalockAsyncTask().execute(map);, what is the type of map that you are passing in? Did you create map like this HashMap<String, String> map or did you just say HashMap map?

Comment: I put HashMap<String, String>:  `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();` then `AmayalockAsyncTask registerUser = new AmayalockAsyncTask(); regusterUser.execute(map);`